# Ошибка в PHP коде при выводе данных из БД PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

```
?php 
require_once"include/db_connect.php";
require_once"functions/functions.php";

$cat = clear_string($_GET["cat"]);
$type = clear_string($_GET["type"]);

$sorting = $_GET["sort"];

switch($sorting){
    case 'price-asc';
    $sorting = 'price ASC';
    $sort_name = 'Від дешевих до дорогих';
    break;

    case 'price-desc';
    $sorting = 'price DESC';
    $sort_name = 'Від дорогих до дешевих';
    break;

    case 'popular';
    $sorting = 'count DESC';
    $sort_name = 'Популярні';
    break;

    case 'news';
    $sorting = 'datatime DESC';
    $sort_name = 'Новинки';
    break;

    case 'brand';
    $sorting = 'brand';
    $sort_name = 'Від А до Я';
    break;
    default:
    $sorting = 'products_id DESC';
    $sort_name = 'Нема сортування';
    break;
}
```

?>


    
        PhpShop

```
            <ul id="block-tovar-grid">
                <?php 
                    if(!empty($cat) && !empty($type)){
                        $query_cat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_tovara='$type'";
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!empty($type)){
                            $query_cat = "type_tovara='$type'";
                        }else{
                            $query_cat = "";
                        }
                        if(!empty($cat)){
                            $catlink = "cat='.$cat.'&";
                        }else{
                            $catlink = "";
                        }
                    }

                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible='1' $query_cat ORDER BY $sorting", $link);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        echo
                        '
                                <div id="block-sorting">
                <p id="nav-breadcrumbs"><a href="index.php">Головна сторінка</a> \ <span>Всі товари</span></p>
                <ul id="option-list">
                    <li>Вид: </li>
                    <li><img id="style-grid" src="images/grid.png"/></li>
                    <li><img id="style-list" src="images/list.png"/></li>
                    <li>Сортування</li>
                    <li><a id="select-sort"><'.$sort_name.'</a>
                        <ul id="sorting-list">
                            <li><a href="view_cat.php?'.$catlink.'type='.$type.'&sort=price-asc">Від дешевих до дорогих</a></li>
                            <li><a href="view_cat.php?'.$catlink.'type='.$type.'&sort=price-desc">Від дорогих до дешевих</a></li>
                            <li><a href="view_cat.php?'.$catlink.'type='.$type.'&sort=popular">Популярні</a></li>
                            <li><a href="view_cat.php?'.$catlink.'type='.$type.'&sort=news">Новинки</a></li>
                            <li><a href="view_cat.php?'.$catlink.'type='.$type.'&sort=brand">Від А до Я</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                        ';
                    do{
                        if($row["image"] != "" && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row["image"])){
                            $img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
                            $max_width = 200;
                            $max_height = 200;
                            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path);
                            $ratioh = $max_height/$height;
                            $ratiow = $max_width/$width;
                            $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
                            $width = intval($ratio*$width);
                            $height = intval($ratio*$height);
                        }
                        else{
                            $img_path = "images/no-image.png";
                            $width = 110;
                            $height = 200;
                        }
                        echo '
                        <li>
                            <div class="block-images-grid">
                                <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>
                            </div>
                            <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></p>
                            <ul class="reviews-and-counts-grid">
                                <li><img src="images/views.png"/><p>0</p></li>
                                <li><img src="images/comments.png"/><p>0</p></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="add-cart-style-grid"></a>
                            <p class="style-price-grid"><strong>'.$row["price"].'</strong> грн.</p>
                            <div class="mini-features">
                                <span style="font-size:13px;">'.$row["mini_features"].'</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>';
                    }while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
                ?>
            </ul>
                <ul id="block-tovar-list">
                <?php 
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible='1' $query_cat ORDER BY $sorting", $link);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    do{
                        if($row["image"] != "" && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row["image"])){
                            $img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
                            $max_width = 150;
                            $max_height = 150;
                            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path);
                            $ratioh = $max_height/$height;
                            $ratiow = $max_width/$width;
                            $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
                            $width = intval($ratio*$width);
                            $height = intval($ratio*$height);
                        }
                        else{
                            $img_path = "images/no-image.png";
                            $width = 80;
                            $height = 70;
                        }
                        echo '
                        <li>
                            <div class="block-images-list">
                                <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="reviews-and-counts-list">
                                <li><img src="images/views.png"/><p>0</p></li>
                                <li><img src="images/comments.png"/><p>0</p></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="style-title-list"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></p>
                            <a class="add-cart-style-list"></a>
                            <p class="style-price-list"><strong>'.$row["price"].'</strong> грн.</p>
                            <div class="style-text-list">
                                '.$row["mini_description"].'
                            </div>
                        </li>';
                    }while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo"<h3>Категорія не доступна або не створенна</h3>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php require_once"include/block-footer.php";?>
    </div>
</body>
```

`

Сама ошибка: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internet-shop.ua\view_cat.php on line 87

Comment: `mysql_query` уже устарел сейчас рекомендуется использовать `mysqli_query` или `pdo`. В целом у вас скорее всего ошибка в запросе к БД, попробуйте перед `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){` вставить `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); echo $row;`. Все остальное задокументировать. Если ничего не выведет то ищите ошибку в `"SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible='1' $query_cat ORDER BY $sorting"`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверять, что получаете от БД

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible='1' $query_cat ORDER BY $sorting", $link);
```

Как то так

```
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){ ...
```

и просмотреть обработку, данных если нет желаемого результата.

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто соединение с БД поставили в конец а не в начало, надо так:

```
$result = mysql_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible='1' $query_cat ORDER BY $sorting");
```

где $link - соединение с БД. А вообще используйте mysqli на крайняк а лучше PDO

Comment: Я учусь по курсам 2014 года и там написано делаем современный магазин, значит не совсем современный.

Comment: Да, всё верно, не совсем современный, хотя в 2014 PDO уже был

Comment: может вы подскажите лучше курсы?

Comment: Курсы я не знаю какие сейчас актуальны обычно ищу отдельные уроки о нужной теме, например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH1nMwEhGwM или https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdC8MMp_LQc